# Merge multiple rows to one row based on same key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have the following data set:

```
key       column1  column2  column3
20171021  1        0        0
20171021  0        1        0
20171021  0        0        1
```

As you can see, the key is the same for all rows.

I need the following output:

```
key       column1  column2  column3
20171021  1        1        1
```

Can anyone help me writing a sql statement that accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple aggregate query:

```
SELECT [key], MAX(column1) column1, MAX(column2) column2, MAX(column3) column3
FROM mytable
GROUP BY [key]
```

Note: I used aggregate function `MAX()`, but given your sample data it could as well be `SUM()` that you need; pick the one that fits your use case.

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation

```
select [key], max(ccolumn1),max(column2) ,max(colum3) from table group by [key]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `max() and group by` to achieve this.

```
select [key], max(column1), max(column2), max(column3) from tableA group by [key]
```